# Java- TreeSet sorting using comparator

Tags: java, data-structures, treeset

I have to write a program which

1. uses a class ShopItem whereby an item the attributes of an item are: barCodeNumber, itemName, price and quantityInStock. Create 5 instances of ShopItems (item1, item2, item3, item4 and item5) with values of my own for their attributes.
2. uses a comparator (barCodeComparator) for ShopItem which allows comparison of ShopItem objects based on their barCodeNumber(Assumption: no two items will never have the same barCode).
3. ensures that two items with the same barCodeNumber cannot be added to the Set.

I am stucked at the 3rd part. I know I have to use a HashSet for that but I do not know how implement it in this program which uses sorting. I am sorry if anything is unclear as I am running out of time since I have a Data Structures test in a few hours.

This is the shopItem.java class

```
public class ShopItem implements Comparable<ShopItem> {

private int barCodeNumber;
private String itemName;
private int price;
private int quantityInStock;

public ShopItem(int barCodeNumber, String itemName, int price, int quantityInStock){

    this.barCodeNumber= barCodeNumber;
    this.itemName= itemName;
    this.price= price;
    this.quantityInStock= quantityInStock;
}


public int getBarCodeNumber() {
    return barCodeNumber;
}


public void setBarCodeNumber(int barCodeNumber) {
    this.barCodeNumber = barCodeNumber;
}


public String getItemName() {
    return itemName;
}


public void setItemName(String itemName) {
    this.itemName = itemName;
}


public int getPrice() {
    return price;
}


public void setPrice(int price) {
    this.price = price;
}


public int getQuantityInStock() {
    return quantityInStock;
}


public void setQuantityInStock(int quantityInStock) {
    this.quantityInStock = quantityInStock;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return "Item: " + itemName+ ":"+ "Bar Code Reader: "+barCodeNumber;
   }

}
```

This is the ShopItem_Order.java class

```
import java.util.*;

public class ShopItem_Order {
final static Comparator<ShopItem> BarCodeComparator= new Comparator<ShopItem>(){

    public int compare(ShopItem A, ShopItem B){

        if(new Integer(A.getBarCodeNumber()).compareTo(new Integer(B.getBarCodeNumber()))<0)

            return -1;

            else if(new Integer(A.getBarCodeNumber()).compareTo(new Integer(B.getBarCodeNumber()))>0)

               return 1;

            else
                return 0;

   }

};



    public static void main(String args[]){

        SortedSet<ShopItem> item= new TreeSet<ShopItem>(new ShopItem_Comparator());

        ShopItem a= new ShopItem(42842, "Iced Green Tea", 75, 20);
        ShopItem b= new ShopItem(42278, "Sugar Free Lindt Choc", 175, 20);
        ShopItem c= new ShopItem(42277, "Red Velvet Cake", 125, 15);
        ShopItem d= new ShopItem(42857, "Financier Cake", 150, 11);
        ShopItem e= new ShopItem(48423, "Tacos", 125, 10);


        item.add(a);
        item.add(b);
        item.add(c);
        item.add(d);
        item.add(e);

        for(ShopItem si: item){
            System.out.println(si.toString());
        }



    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

since your bar code as unique criteria you can use it for hashCode calculation. E.g. return new Integer(barCodeNumber).hashCode(). Be aware that you also need to implement equals() method which also will be based on barCodeNumber.

Comment: There is nothing about map. Mentioned TreeSet is an ok choice, just to implement equals() for proper work

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a comparator, why do you have to use a HashSet and not a TreeSet? Implement equalsTo in a way that is consistent with your comparator (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

If sorting is a requirement, you should stick with TreeSet which offers ordering. Hashset relies on hash values, thus, no sorting.

Also your comparator can be simplified to a one liner:

```
return Integer.valueOf(a.getBarcodeNumber().compare(Integer.valueOf(b.getBarCodeNumber());
```